# jquery colorbox requires two clicks to fire

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a button in which when I click, a colorbox event is fired. However on the very first time, it requires two clicks to fire. Subsequently it only needs one click to fire

My jquery for colorbox is as below

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-trigger='colorbox']",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentTarget = $(e.currentTarget);
    if(currentTarget.data("inline") !== true){
        currentTarget.colorbox();
    }else if(currentTarget.data("inline") === true){
        currentTarget.colorbox({inline : true, href : currentTarget.data("href")});
    }
 });
```

My html as below

```
<div class="float-right">
    <div class="span3 push-v">
        <a href="#" class="move_on btn-large btn-inverse" data-trigger="colorbox" data-inline="true" data-href="#choose">
            I like this, lets move on
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <div id="choose">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                    <!--Content-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because first click assigning colorbox to DOM and second click call colorbox itself..

Comment: you should instantiate your colorbox on dom or jquery ready, then you assign your events to control colorbox behaviour

Comment: Thanks tt was helpful. issues resolved!